# Basic Springboot app throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having a problem with SpringBoot.  I have an exception handler in my controller.  Every time I throw an exception that is caught by the controller, it returns the correct values to the client, but it also puts a lot of NPEs in the log.  This is mostly an annoyance, but a lot of insignificant errors in the log can mask real problems.

Is there a way to fix this?  I am also submitting it to the Spring boot people.

The error looks like this:

```
2017-03-17 22:45:09.800  INFO 4166 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-17 22:45:09.815  INFO 4166 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 14 ms
2017-03-17 22:45:09.861  WARN 4166 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public java.lang.String com.test.error.controllers.TestCtlr.return400(java.security.InvalidParameterException)

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:384) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1218) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

I recreated this by creating a bare-bones app using Spring Boot Initializer with version 1.5.2.  The entire app appears below.  It has only one controller.

I did notice that if spring-boot-starter-data-rest is included in the pom, the problem occurs.  If it is omitted, the problem does not occur.

```
package com.test.error;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have a very simple controller with one method that succeeds and another that always throws an exception.

```
package com.test.error.controllers;

import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.error.dto.TestDTO;

@RestController
public class TestCtlr {

    @RequestMapping(path="/test/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<TestDTO> findAll() {

        List<TestDTO> sectionDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        sectionDTOs.add(new TestDTO(1, "DTO1"));
         sectionDTOs.add(new TestDTO(2, "DTO2"));

        return sectionDTOs;

    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/test/findAllErr", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<TestDTO> findAllErr() {

        throw new InvalidParameterException("Reason for exc");

    }

   @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
   @ExceptionHandler(InvalidParameterException.class)
   public String return400(InvalidParameterException ex) {
       return ex.getMessage();

   }

}
```

TestDTO is a very simple class:

```
package com.test.error.dto;

public class TestDTO {

    private int id;
    private String description;

    public TestDTO() {}

    public TestDTO(int id, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }   
}
```

And now the pom.  Again, it does not occur if spring-boot-starter-data-rest is omitted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.error</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Putting your `@ExceptionHandler` method into a dedicated `@RestControllerAdvice` should fix the problem.

**TestCtrlAdvice.java**

```
package com.test.error.controllers;

import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

@RestControllerAdvice
public class TestCtlrAdvice {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidParameterException.class)
    public String return400(InvalidParameterException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();

    }
}
```

As for "why", I cannot give you an answer. I always put my exception handlers into a dedicated class. Explanations would be welcome.

---

**EDIT**

Explanations available in the related issue.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1031

---

**EDIT (2)**

As said in the linked ticket, this issue is fixed in versions 
`3.0 M4 (Kay)`, `2.5.12 (Hopper SR12)` and `2.6.5 (Ingalls SR5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  I will do that. I would still like to see them fix the bug.

Comment: Great workaround. Better than defining a base rest controller.
Thanks a lot.