# @ExceptionHandler null pointer in console after spring-boot upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Today, I was feeling a bit lucky, so I upgraded from Spring boot 1.5.1 to the latest. When I run my JAR file, everything seems fine at first.

However, when I make a call that is expected to return an error response (negative test - say "record not found"), it returns a properly formatted JSON response as expected.

However, I also notice a giant stack-trace in the console.

There is a WARN level log which mentions a null pointer somewhere.

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - 
Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: protected org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>     com.sgb.AbstractBaseController.handle(com.sgb.panic.CustomSgbException,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest)
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
```

It was working perfectly fine before I upgraded to the latest spring boot 1.5.3.
When I switched back to 1.5.1, the stack trace goes away.
I switch to 1.5.3, it comes back.

What gives?
Appreciate any pointers.

EDIT:
When I change the logging level of spring framework to DEBUG, I see that immediately after the above stack trace is logged, it attempts to call the ExceptionHandler again and succeeds the second time - which explains why a valid error response was coming despite the stack trace.

The question then becomes why :

```
 o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method
```

the first invocation to @ExceptionHandler method is failing.

EDIT:
[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871047/basic-springboot-app-throws-nullpointerexception) also refers to this problem.

In my case, I have an AbstractBaseController class that all my controllers extend where all the exception handling occurs instead of having a separate ControllerAdvice for my Rest endpoint.

I attempted to create a separate ControllerAdvice for handling all exceptions. It works for all my custom exceptions, however when validation failure triggered by @Valid (JSR-303) occurs, it does not get seem to trigger my custom ExceptionHandler in my ControllerAdvice for MethodArgumentNotValidException. This results in an empty 400 with no error message when JSR 303 validations fail.

So I need to move all my exception handlers back into the superclass for the controllers which results in the original WARN message in the log. This is less than ideal.

Comment: Will probably need a more detailed stack trace to figure this out...

Comment: I found this issue opened in spring's github repo which seems related: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1031

Comment: This post also refers to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871047/basic-springboot-app-throws-nullpointerexception

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in SpringDataRest which causes this side-effect. We happen to use SDR also in our app. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1031

Comment: A bug has also been opened in spring-boot which notes this regression due to the SDR bug:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8659

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same problem with the `1.5.3-RELEASE` version.

Upgrading to the `1.5.8-RELEASE` solved the bug.

Comment: Mr. Fradegrada, you have absolutely saved me another day of staring blankly at my ******* screen. Thank you!